# DailyRollingFileAppender alternative in Log4j 2x

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

DailyRollingFileAppender was removed in Log4j 2x. What should be used instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `RollingFile` <sup>**1**</sup> with `TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy` <sup>**2**</sup>. e.g.:

```xml
<RollingFile name="RollingFile" 
             fileName="/tmp/app.log"
             filePattern="/tmp/app%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
    <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n" />
    <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
</RollingFile>
```

See more in [*Apache Log4j 2 User's Guide*](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/) [[**PDF**](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-users-guide.pdf)].

---

*Notes*

1. [`org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.RollingFileAppender`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/RollingFileAppender.html)
2. [`org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.rolling.TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy`](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/log4j-core/apidocs/org/apache/logging/log4j/core/appender/rolling/TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy.html)

Answer (score 1):

If, like me, you're finally getting around to upgrading to log4j2 – because of the log4shell vulnerability – and you are accustomed to DailyRollingFileAppender rolling over at midnight, you should make that:

```
<TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy modulate="true" />
```